# How to dump functions, args and return values in PHP?

Tags: php, c, zend-api

I am a pentester working on a project and I stumbled on an encrypted PHP file. My idea is trying to modify PHP's source code so it dumps every function called name, arg names, arg types, and values.

I tried modifying the _zend_vm_stack_push_call_frame_ex function in the zend_execute.c according to the picture bellow but dumping the arg names is not working.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to implement this properly or at least tell me what I am doing wrong on dumping the arg names?

Comment: I think the best way to go about this is just to use a debugger

Comment: @vmt I tried using the trace functionality of xdebug but I could not make it work.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

So basically there are internal functions and user functions. User functions contains an array of arg_info of type zend_string while internal functions contains an array of internal_arg_info of type const char*.

[image]

This is the current code which dumps arg names properly:

[image]